# Backbone JS Button Click Event Not Working

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone js and I'm struggling to display an alert when clicking on the button displayed in the html page. I am certain I'm doing something foolish, but when i click the button the event doesn't seem to be fired. I have tried to use both submit and click in the events section, but I can't seem to get it to work. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Event Test</title>
  <script src="../../external/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../../external/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="../../external/backbone.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>
<div id="standard-input-form"></div>
<script>

  var MovePalletView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
  },

  events: {
    'submit' : 'move'
  },

  render: function(event) {
    this.$el.append('<button type="button" value="Submit"></button>');
    $("#standard-input-form").html(this.$el.html());
    return this;
  },

  move: function() { 
    alert("You clicked it");
    }
  });

  $(function(){ 
    var movePalletView = new MovePalletView()
    movePalletView.render();      
   })

  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render function appends just HTML string which doesn't have any events bound. Instead append HTML element (just remove `.html()` part):

```
events: {
    'click' : 'move'
},

render: function(event) {
    this.$el.append('<button type="button" value="Submit"></button>');
    $("#standard-input-form").html(this.$el);
    return this;
},
```

However, this is not really a good solution, because you would have to use click event instead of proper submit. Much better approach is to initialize your `MovePalletView` with `#standard-input-form` as `this.$el`:

```
var MovePalletView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#standard-input-form',
    initialize: function () {},

    events: {
        'submit': 'move'
    },

    render: function (event) {
        this.$el.append('<button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>');
        return this;
    },

    move: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You clicked it");
    }
});
```

A few notes. First of all, make sure you have button `type="submit"` it will trigger `onsubmit` event. Then you need to create View object on the form element as the root (`el: '#standard-input-form'`). Then you will be able to bind to its onsubmit event.

Comment: Thanks! I will make those changes, really appreciate the quick help!

Comment: i'm still not getting the alert message box to display after adding these changes, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check everything, here is the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8BDMy80lRZsKScqmrPjW?p=info

Comment: Ah, got it! You changed the standard input declaration from div to the following and now it works. <form id="standard-input-form"></form>. Thank you so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Feel free to accept the answer if you want.

Comment: thanks, just accepted it. This actually the first question I've ever posed so I wasn't sure what the proper protocol was.

Answer (score 2):

In the event there are any other newbie's out there reviewing this question, this was the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dairy Tracker</title>
  <script src="../../external/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../../external/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="../../external/backbone.js"></script>  
  <script src="src/MovePallet.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>
<form id="standard-input-form"></form>
<script>

var MovePalletView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#standard-input-form',
    initialize: function () {},

    events: {
        'submit': 'move'
    },

    render: function (event) {
        this.$el.append('<button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>');
        return this;
    },

    move: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //this line keeps the page from refreshing after   closing the following alert.
      alert("You clicked it");
    }
});

$(function(){ 
  var movePalletView = new MovePalletView()
  movePalletView.render();      
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```